# When I change the width of container <div>, the inside <div> should also change accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent `<div>`

```
.container{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    top:20%;
    left:30%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

If I change the width of parent div, the position of child div (here box)           doesnt change.

```
.box{                           
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;  
    top: 20;  
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: dynamic width for `.box` `width:100%` (if you have a single one)

Comment: @AdamAzad He meant the position of the `div`.

Comment: have tried position relative to the parent? @Anitha

Comment: It should be noted that `top:20` is not a valid value....`top:20px` would be...or `top:20%`...as it is, it's invalid.

Comment: http://codepen.io/agasthyanavaneeth/pen/oLozBA

Comment: You should try like, .box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 20px;
}

Comment: Why would change the position? The position is relative to the top left corner of the parent, change the width of the parent does not affect the position of the child

Answer (score 0):

You can set % on positions as well:
Check this viz : [link](http://codepen.io/agasthyanavaneeth/pen/oLozBA)

```css
.container{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    top:20%;
    left:30%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
.box{                           
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;  
    top: 20%;  
    left: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in % the coordinates of your inner `<div>`. It will change his position according to his parent's size.

```css
.container{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    top:20%;
    left:30%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;

}
.box{                           
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;  
    top: 20%; 
    left:20%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```